# Laravel named routes array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Named routes, the best thing that's created by Laravel. But is it's possible in some way to add an array of named routes which can be used?

I did the follow:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => ['url', 'secondurl'],
    'uses' => 'ViewController@index'
]);
```

but it returned an eror, `Illegal offset type`.

Is this simply not possible or did I do something wrong?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by having a route with 2 names? There is probably just a different approach that would accomplish something similar

Comment: @RobFonseca someone declared the named route 2 time and he assinged it already in almost every file...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can only set one name for each of the route. [Check the documentations here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)

Hope my answer helps =)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the documentation but that's why I asked it here. But unfortunately it's not possible.